# how maven resolve javax.servlet.servlet-api and javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api conflict

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

my maven dependency tree like this

[image]
i want to ask i how maven resolve this conflict, has two servlet-api.jar?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maven resolves version conflicts with a nearest-wins strategy.
You can refer to [Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add exclusion if you want to remove the `servlet-api` from the Velocity Tools.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```